# beautifulsoup4 not finding HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape chat messages, but when prompted to print, outputs none and exits with a code 0. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
# import libraries, pip install beautifulsoup4.
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 
'https://robertsspaceindustries.com/spectrum/community/SC/lobby/8'

#finding
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find('messages-items', attrs={'message-item status-default': 
'content'})
print name

#logging
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name, datetime.now()])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you watch closely when oppening Chrome Network Tools or Firebug, you'll notice that your website requests a webservice to fetch the data that you want.

You'll need to simulate a post with three parameters:

- `before` which is the last id received to get new messages;
- `lobby_id` which is the current lobby you want to fetch;
- `size` which is how many messages to fetch

It'll return an json object in which you only need to parse to get the results you want;

Here's an example:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.post('https://robertsspaceindustries.com/api/spectrum/message/history', data = {'before': None, 'lobby_id':'8', 'size':'50'})
lobby_data = json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))

for comment in lobby_data["data"]["messages"]:
  print ("%s: %s" % (comment["member"]["displayname"], comment["content_state"]["blocks"][0]["text"]))
```

Which outputs:

```
Antinov: Esp since spectrum doesn't even open a new tab to view large images....
Sir Quentin Reginald Watson: write a suggestion about it
Antinov: As if CIG listens to those.
Sir Quentin Reginald Watson: you will never know if you don't try
....
```